# Php: creating directory

Tags: php, mkdir

I am trying to create folder and sub folder on website. Code is pretty simple. Not sure why does not work.

```
<?php

$domain = "officeactionuspto.com";

mkdir(($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/crc/website_templates/client_files/'.$domain), 0777, true);
mkdir(($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/crc/website_templates/client_files/'.$domain.'/images'), 0777, true);


$folder= $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/crc/website_templates/client_files/'.$domain.'/images';


if(is_dir($folder))
  {
  echo ("$folder is a directory");
  }
else
  {
  echo ("$folder is not a directory");
  }

?>
```

Comment: We're not sure either.

Comment: bet you a dollar its a permission issue

Comment: Permission ? it does not like my 0777 ?

Comment: for future reference you can create both at once with the recursive parameter. Also check what gets returned from mkdir, false on error

Comment: According to the docs, it will behave different on Windows server as opposed to Linux. Are you on a Linux server?

Comment: Yes the website is on the linux server

Comment: just because the user wants to set the permission to 0777 does not mean the user has the permission to do so.

Comment: And the 'user' in this case is the script trying to create the directory. What does that script run as? Which user is it?

Comment: Your folder client_files must provide write+execute permissions for your webserver user (apache or www or whatever it is on your server)

Comment: You can login as webserver user (e.g. `su - apache`) and do it manually on console. Then you'll see the permission errors.

Comment: The problem is that we pay for that sever to IT company, so we don't really control server. they handle all the support regarding server issues and security. So, I contacted them, told the, mkdir does not work.. even a very simple one.. so what else should I tell them?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use absolute path to create a directory.

You can just do it with following code:

```php
mkdir('images', 0777, true);


$folder= 'images';

if(is_dir($folder)){
  echo ("$folder is a directory");
}else{
  echo ("$folder is not a directory");
}
```

you can also get the absolute path after created, if you desired:

```
$full_path = realpath('images');
```

PS: I'm supposing you are executing this code on /index.php, if was on another different structure, you need to write the relative path for it.

**EDIT: I tested and eliminate a parentheses on mkdir and works.**

Comment: yeah, but what if I want my folder to be in different folder from my php file?

Comment: I have tried to a relevent path just like on the example below. It did not work.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to use the entire, absolute filename. You just need to use the path relative to the folder where the script being executed is located.

Although I don't know your file structure, lets pretend that the PHP script is in the `crc` folder: Your command would be: `mkdir(('/website_templates/client_files/'.$domain), 0777, true);`

**EDIT:** With the recursive parameter, you can create the images subfolder in the same command.

Comment: I edited my answer: Add a forward slash at the beginning of the string.

Comment: Have you tried creating the directory with other permissions? 0755 for example?

Comment: Yes, I have tried different permissions and no permissions at all. It just does not want to create the folder no matter what.